# Problems updating Debian 6

Tags: debian-squeeze, update, aptitude, linux

Im trying to update a Debian 6 server, but get the following output with some errors after `sudo aptitude update`:

```
Ign http://archive.debian.org oldstable Release.gpg
Ign http://archive.debian.org/debian/ oldstable/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://archive.debian.org/debian/ oldstable/main Translation-en
Ign http://archive.debian.org/debian/ oldstable/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://archive.debian.org oldstable Release
Hit http://ftp.debian.org squeeze-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://archive.debian.org oldstable/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://ftp.debian.org squeeze-updates Release
Ign http://archive.debian.org oldstable/contrib amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.debian.org oldstable/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.debian.org oldstable/main amd64 Packages
Ign http://archive.debian.org oldstable/contrib amd64 Packages
Hit http://ftp.debian.org squeeze-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates Release.gpg
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/main Translation-en
Ign http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates/non-free Translation-en
Ign http://archive.debian.org oldstable/non-free amd64 Packages
Hit http://ftp.debian.org squeeze-updates/contrib amd64 Packages
Hit http://ftp.debian.org squeeze-updates/non-free amd64 Packages
Err http://archive.debian.org oldstable/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 206.12.19.126 80]
Err http://archive.debian.org oldstable/contrib amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 206.12.19.126 80]
Err http://archive.debian.org oldstable/non-free amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found [IP: 206.12.19.126 80]
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates Release
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/contrib amd64 Packages
Hit http://security.debian.org squeeze/updates/non-free amd64 Packages
```

This is my sources.list:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian oldstable main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
```

This sources was generated from http://debgen.simplylinux.ch/

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `oldstable` to `lenny`.

If you look into the http-repository, there is no folder `oldstable`. Hence the 404.

http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/oldstable (404)
http://archive.debian.org/debian/dists/lenny (200)

If you do not know why you have certain things in your sources list (archive/oldstable), I recommend to use this list:

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main
#deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze main contrib non-free

# Security Updates
deb http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free
#deb-src http://security.debian.org/ squeeze/updates main contrib non-free

# squeeze-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main
#deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ squeeze-updates main

# testing or sid
#deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ testing main
#deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ unstable main

# Dotdeb Archive
#deb http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
#deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org squeeze all
```

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand, lenny is Debian 5..., elaborate please

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Ok, and why there is not a squeeze folder then?

Comment: Wyvern, I answered your question. I would appreciate, if you could tell me if that fixed your problem. If you have further questions, you should ask a new question. You can also read more about the sources list here. https://wiki.debian.org/SourcesList

Comment: Yes, now it works. I think you had a typo at the start of your answer, you first  said "change oldstable to lenny"... now in your last edit you changed oldstable for squeeze.

Comment: Yeah, that was a wrong assumption. Oldstable is squeeze. I wrote lenny because you were using squeeze and I thought you meant lenny with oldstable. Nevermind. Glad you got it working.